# Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException Error after NGX Update

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Hello fellow Automation QAs :)

Our Project front-end was updated on few places with some new ngx-bootstrap which led to many Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException Errors at many places.

Do you guys have some out of the box / unorthodox ideas on what the issue might be. I have never encountered similar issue.

I am currently handling those errors on some places using JavaScript to Click but its not always suitable.
Action class click also helps on some places but for other it just wont work at all.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code attempts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [repro], otherwise we do not have enough information to provide an answer.